# JQuery and Angular: Add two functions in ng-keydown

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Adding two functions in ng-keydown through the use of jQuery attr

How can I do this the right way.

```
$('#id').attr('ng-keydown', 'maxinput(), numericOnly()');
```

Comment: Implement validator directives rather than handle ng-keydown and calling functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @pixelbits that you should [create a custom validator](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation) for the purpose you are trying to achieve. In fact, you can even use [ng-maxlength](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input) and set [input type to `number`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D) to have the validation you require OOTB.

But if you really want to call multiple functions in an `ng-*` handler (it can be click, keydown etc), you should separate calls with semicolon `;` instead of comma.

You might also want to read [how to think in Angular way with jQuery background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background).